# $stateParams converting value to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I am using `UI-Router`. Here's one of my state to which I am routing via `ui-sref`:

```
.state("community", {
    url: "/community/:community_id",
    controller: "CommunityCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/static/templates/community.html"
})
```

In one of my templates from where I go to 'community' state:

```
<div ui-sref="community({community_id: community.community_id})"></div>
```

Here's my community object:

```
{
    name: 'Community name',
    community_id: 11 //int, not a string
}
```

As you can see the key 'community_id' contains an int value rather than string value. However, when I access this parameter via `$stateParams` I get:

```
community_id: "11" //string
```

Why am I getting a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to get **`community_id`** as number *(int)* is to declare that param as `int` - `{community_id:int}`

```
.state("community", {
    url: "/community/{community_id:int}",
    controller: "CommunityCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/static/templates/community.html"
})
```

Check the doc about [`.state()` setting **`url`**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider):

> A `url` fragment with optional parameters. When a state is navigated or transitioned to, the `$stateParams` service will be populated with any parameters that were passed.
>
> (See UrlMatcher UrlMatcher} for more details on acceptable patterns )
>
> examples:
>
> ```
> url: "/home"
> url: "/users/:userid"
> url: "/books/{bookid:[a-zA-Z_-]}"
> url: "/books/{categoryid:int}"
> url: "/books/{publishername:string}/{categoryid:int}"
> url: "/messages?before&after"
> url: "/messages?{before:date}&{after:date}"
> url: "/messages/:mailboxid?{before:date}&{after:date}"
> ```

Comment: @RadimKöhler Just one question, for `date` type, do we need to specify a format?

Comment: @PankajParkar hope here you get the answer: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/urlMatcherFactory.js#L42

Comment: @RadimKöhler I got that..I need to think about refactoring in my application..Thanks alot man..  +1 appreciated help on additional question..