# $stateParams coming in as array, but how to convert in string?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to perform Master-Detail Page.
I used $stateParams.id to bring detailed data.

The problem is that $stateParams.id is returned as array.

Which means,
If the data is like:
**{id: 1, name:'James'}, {id:2, name:'John'}**

and when **$stateParams.id is 1**,

Then the returned data is **ID:2. Not ID:1** as it is returned as array and it is selected as array[1].

**I think it is because the PHP is returning the data as array().**

I don't know where to fix: the AngularJS or PHP? (Or I might be wrong at all!)
Which one would you fix? Please advise me.

[controller.js]

```
function ProjectCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout, $state, $stateParams, $location) {

  $http.post("../crud/projects_read.php", {
    })
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.projects = response.data;
        $scope.project_data = $scope.projects[$stateParams.id];
    });
  };
```

[config.js]

```
.state('pjt.project_detail', {
        url: "/project_detail/{id}",
        templateUrl: 'views/project_detail.html',
        data: { pageTitle: 'Project detail' },
        controller: 'ProjectCtrl',
    })
```

[projects_read.php]

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `projects`") or die(mysqli_error());
    $data = array();
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

**My goal is to be like:

$stateParams.id matches the id number of the data as string, NOT as array.**

Thank you in advance for your support!

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673113/stateparams-converting-value-to-string

Comment: Don't see how you are getting array from url ... doesn't really make sense

Comment: don't read **all** your projects from the server if you are only displaying one on the page;  call an API method that takes the `id` and returns a single object instead.

Answer (score 0):

To figure out whether the problem is with AngularJS or PHP, can you please provide the **exact** response the PHP script gives?

If the PHP scripts returns the data as **single** JSON objects as

```
{id: 1, name:'James'}, {id:2, name:'John'}
```

rather than a sequence/array of JSON objects as

```
[{id: 1, name:'James'}, {id:2, name:'John'}]
```

then you have to make some changes in the PHP script.

If we say that this is the culprit, then the error can be justified but we can't say anything for sure until you provide the exact php response.

If the the response is an array of JSON objects then the error might be a mistake.

Recall, that in order to access the data of the **project ID# 2**, we have to reference the response array with the index of 1, because javascript array indexes are **0-based**.

So `$scope.projects[1]` will return `{id: 2, name: "John"}` and `$scope.projects[0]` will return `'{id: 1, name: "James"}'`

If this is the case then what i recommend is to change the PHP script so that **you don't get the entire list of projects but only the one you want**.

You can do this by passing the project id to the PHP script in the POST call you make through AngularJS and then using the id in the MySQL query to get the specific project details.

Hope i helped.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I get [{id: 1, name:'James'}, {id:2, name:'John'}] instead of {id: 1, name:'James'}, {id:2, name:'John'}. How can $stateParams be connected to the ID which is the KEY?